Create new List when Button is pressed
How can I generate a new List by clicking on a Button?
Can it be done using a loop or something similar?
List<List<Countries>> groups = [];
...
child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              int numberOfGroups = groups.length;
              int nextGroup = numberOfGroups++;
              String number = nextGroup.toString();
              List<Countries> number = [];
              groups.add(number);
              });
              },

This doesnt work :(

You need to explain better what data structure you have, and what you want to have after the button is pressed.

Try this:
List<List<Countries>> groups = [];

...

child: GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    setState(() {
      int numberOfGroups = groups.length;
      int nextGroup = numberOfGroups + 1;
  
      List<Countries> newGroup = [];
      groups.add(newGroup);
    });
  },
),

